# How can I display a graph with its weights inside the vertices and its labels just outside?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the following graph:

```
Graph[
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}} // Map[Apply[UndirectedEdge]],
    VertexWeight -> {10, 20, 30, 40},
    VertexLabels -> Placed["VertexWeight", Center],
    VertexSize -> Medium
]
```

which is displayed as follows:

[image: A sample graph]

But what I would like is to have the weights inside the circles, and the names, i.e., {1, 2, 3, 4}, just outside each circle.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to draw the graph twice with different labels:

```
Show[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4},
    UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}},
    VertexWeight -> {10, 20, 30, 40},
    VertexLabels -> #,
    VertexSize -> Medium] & /@
  {"Name", Placed["VertexWeight", Center]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried `VertexLabels -> {"Name", Placed["VertexWeight", Center]}`, but did not think to render the graph twice.

Answer (score 3):

If getting a `Graphics` object is ok Bob Hanlon's method is the cleanest way I can think of.

If you need a `Graph` object with multiple vertex labels, you can do it in a number of ways, including:

**1.**

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4},
  UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}} ,
  VertexWeight -> {10, 20, 30, 40}, 
  VertexSize -> Medium];

 Graph[g, VertexLabels -> 
   {v_ :> Placed[{AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], v}, {Center, {After, Above}}]}]
```

[image]

**2.**

```
(AnnotationValue[{g, #}, VertexLabels] = 
  Placed[{AnnotationValue[{g, #}, VertexWeight], #}, {Center, {After, Above}}]) & /@
  VertexList[g];
g
```

[image]

**3.**

```
vWeights = AssociationThread[Range[4], {10, 20, 30, 40}];

Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4},
 UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}} ,
 VertexWeight -> Values @ vWeights, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :>  
    Placed[{vWeights @ v, "Name"}, {Center, {After, Above}}]}, 
  VertexSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Your first method is very good. Thanks!

Comment: @kglr: Is there some way to show the $2$ to be on the RHS of the node like the others?

Comment: @Moo, the relative positions (with respect to the vertex positions) of all four labels are the same.

Comment: @kglr: I totally missed that, however, visually, it is not very clean looking.

Comment: @Moo, perhaps you can try something like `Placed[{AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], 
  v}, {Center, {1.25, .75}}]`.